# How to get instance of current message bein processed in cxf?

Tags: cxf

I want to get the ID of the Inbound message in my implemented service end point which has following parameters available:

1. Custom JAXB Request
2. @Context HttpServletRequest

   e.g. From below inbound message i want to retrieve ID: 1 in my service endpoint.
   INFO: Inbound Message

   ID: 1
   Address: 
   Encoding: ISO-8859-1
   Http-Method: POST
   Content-Type: application/xml
   Headers:
   Payload:

Can anyone please tell me if there is a way to get that ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current CXF [Message](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Message.html) using [PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/phase/PhaseInterceptorChain.html#getCurrentMessage%28%29). The logging ID used by the logging interceptors is stored in the Message Map, and can be retrieved with its key, e.g.

```
String loggingId = (String) PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().get(LoggingMessage.ID_KEY);
```